# How can I persist login session after redirect laravel 4.2

Tags: php, apache, session

I have a Laravel 4.2 project working fine locally with Xampp. 
On the production server my Sessions do not persist after a redirect, so that after a login I get redirected back to the login, as auth fails at the next page.
I have established that if this is caused by

`Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure`
included in httpd.conf.
(I can re-produce the behaviour on Xampp with this edit of httpd.conf.)
My sessions are stored in the database. Does anybody know of a workaround, my production server is on shared hosting.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer that might not be ideal is to use a GET variable to store the session ID instead of a cookie. PHP supports that transparently but it's often overlooked.